# Длительная пауза при неудачном выполнении скрипта на Python

Tags: python, linux, golang

Описание: в системе крутится демон,написанный на golang'е, одна из задач которого - запустить на машине скрипт на python'е, исходный код которого ему прилетает по сети. Функция, осуществляющая вызов интерпретатора:

```
func ExecutePyScript(args []byte) error {
    path, err := exec.LookPath("python2")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pyscript, err := ioutil.TempFile("/tmp", "ev3_pycmd_")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer os.Remove(pyscript.Name())

    var rc error = nil
    if _, err := pyscript.Write(args); err == nil {
        var errBuf bytes.Buffer
        var outBuf bytes.Buffer

        cmd := exec.Command(path, pyscript.Name())
        cmd.Stdout = &outBuf
        cmd.Stderr = &errBuf

        if rerr := cmd.Run(); rerr != nil {
            rc = rerr
        }
    } else {
        rc = err
    }

    pyscript.Close()

    return rc
}
```

Суть проблемы: интепретатор "уходит в себя", когда пытается выполнить скрипт, в котором имеются синтаксические ошибки, не указаны необходимые импорты и т.д. Если запустить скрипт вручную - наблюдается то же самое - мы видим сообщение об ошибке, но при этом процесс не завершается. Соответственно, демон не может дождаться результата выполнения скрипта и не отдает никакого фидбэка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: незнаю поможет ли это вам, но я бы приходящий скрипт обернул в try except

Comment: @0xdef, в том-то и дело, что интерпретатор может лечь еще до выполнения каких-либо инструкций; грубо говоря - ошиблись с отступами - и все, дальше будет то, что описано выше в посте.

Comment: @0xdef, но за совет спасибо, попробую, вдруг я чего-то не доглядел.

Comment: Перед выполнением скрипта запускайте `pylint <script.py>`. Будет ругаться, можно даже не пытаться запускать.

Comment: @0andriy, спасибо!